# Read content of a file to string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, file, internet-explorer, filereader

On my website I got a form with an input:

```
<input type="file" id="text">
```

I'd like to get a content of a text file into a string variable using JavaScript. I used `File API`, but obviously it's not working in IE or some older browsers. I tried to use `new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` but some security reasons won't let me use it in IE, as it gives me an error: "Automation Server can't create object". From what I read, it seems to me that this cannot be used then without changing some security options in a browser and that's not what I want my users to do.

So is there any other simple way to read a file's content by using JavaScript only and to make it work in older browsers?

Comment: I don't think so. You can try uploading the file to a server and then reading it back from the server using AJAX.

Comment: Well, uploading the file is a thing I wanted to resign from, but thanks

Comment: @TedHopp you cannot upload file via ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most older browsers, no.  There are some strict security limitations for Javascript.

If you are focusing IE/Windows-only and are trying to write something for your own local use, then HTA files have access to read-write routines.

Comment: Thank you for a reply but sadly HTA files aren't satisfying for me.